# d3.js selection and call() conundrum

Tags: select, d3.js, call, cubism.js

i have the following bit of `d3` (cubism) code in a coffeescript class:

```
d3.select("view").selectAll(".horizon")
    .data( @metrics )
  .enter()
    .insert("div", ".bottom")
    .attr("class", "horizon")
  .call( @ctx.horizon() )
```

and everything works great. however, i would like to pass the following data structure into my class to instantiate the 'view':

```
metricGroup =
  cpu:
    extent: [0,100]
  temperature:
    extent: [0,80]
  power:
    scale: d3.scale.ordinal( [0,1,2] ).range( [-2,1,-1] )
    extent: [-2,1]
```

as you can see, i wish to associate certain `scale` and `extent`s to each metric. each metric (would) define specific calls to each `horizon` object that needs to be chained in the above `d3` code such that:

```
.call( 
  @ctx.horizon()
    .scale(@metricGroup.power.scale)
    .extent(@metricGroup.power.extent) 
)
```

so for the 'power' metric, it would be

```
.call(
  @ctx.horizon()
    .scale(d3.scale.ordinal( [0,1,2] ).range( [-2,1,-1] ))
    .extent( [-2,1] )
)
```

how could i keep the elegance of the select/enter/call method chain, yet provide the customisation i want?

Comment: Have you tried making the scales etc part of the data you pass in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit constrained here because I'm only somewhat familiar with cubism, and I can't stand coffeescript :). But it looks like you probably want to define functions for your horizon properties, as per the "array of languages" example [here (scroll up one paragraph)](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Horizon#wiki-_horizon). I don't know what `@metrics` is in your code, but if you used an array of key names, e.g. `["cpu", "temperature", ...]` you could do the lookup in the functions, e.g. (sorry, switching to js):

```
.call(
    ctx.horizon()
       .scale(function(d) { return metricGroup[d].scale || defaultScale; })
       // etc
)
```